# Override layout by XML to use custom template

Tags: layout, template, xml, phtml

I am trying to use a custom addtocart.phtml.

Currently magento is using `app/design/frontend/default/customtheme/template/catalog/product/view/addtocart.phtml`

I want to change it to `app/design/frontend/base/default/template/my_module/catalog/product/view/addtocart.phtml`

I created a module and this is a part of my config.xml:

```
<layout>
        <updates>
            <My_Module>
                <file>my_module.xml</file>
            </My_Module>
        </updates>
      </layout>
    </frontend>
```

The file my_module.xml is located at `app/design/frontend/base/default/layout/my_module.xml`

Can anybody help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how your my_module.xml layout should look like if you want to change the addtocart template:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout version="0.1.0">
    <catalog_product_view> 
        <reference name="product.info.addtocart">
            <action method="setTemplate"><template>my_module/catalog/product/view/addtocart.phtml</template></action>
        </reference>
    </catalog_product_view>
</layout>
```

if you need to do it for the review page as well, add the following between the layout tags of the code I posted above:

```
    <review_product_list> 
        <reference name="product.info.addtocart">
            <action method="setTemplate"><template>my_module/catalog/product/view/addtocart.phtml</template></action>
        </reference>
    </review_product_list>
```